# Incompatibility of Nexus Style Class and mhchem

Tags: mhchem

I was very impressed with the nexus style class on the latex showcase (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336851/166730)). Unfortunately when I tried to implement it, I needed to load the mhchem package and when doing so, the tabs at the bottom fail to render properly:

## Normal:

[image]

## When Loading `mhchem` package:

[image]

As you can see, not only is the page footer the wrong colour, it is also lacking the tabs.

Here is my not working code:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% Geometry
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Les paquets

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[palette=munch]{nexus}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% hyperref
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[verbose]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ 
    hidelinks
}
\setlength{\XeTeXLinkMargin}{-1pt}
\usepackage{mhchem} % <----- MHCHEM, COMMENT THIS LINE AND COMPILE TWICE TO SEE PROPER LAYOUT

\begin{document}

\include{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This is a Chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]


\chapter{This is a Chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\chapter{This is a Chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{This is a Chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]


%%%%%%
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{This is a Chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{This is a Chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]


\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The relevant class files can be found from the creator's github repository available [here](https://github.com/alexisflesch/nexus). One will notice that the above code is simply the test.tex with `\usepackage{mhchem}` added in which causes the error.

## Things I have tried

I have tried following some suggestions from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407108/strange-interaction-between-fontspec-and-mhchem) and added `\mhchemoptions{text-greek=default, math-greek=default}` to the line after `\usepackage{mhchem}` but alas to no avail. It did not solve my problem. I am not sure what is causing this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your style loads `assoccnt`. mhchem loads `calc`. As the documentation of `assoccnt` says:

> This package does not work really well with the  calc package. Load 
>   calc before assoccnt

So move mhchem before nexus.

Comment: This resolves the issue, thank you